# Installing package with gdebi incorrectly finding newer version of package

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation, emacs

I am trying to install Emacs version 25.1. I have the `.deb` package for this, which I created using `checkinstall`. This was part of [the short tutorial that I followed](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/09/install-gnu-emacs-25-1-in-ubuntu-16-04/) (perhaps the clue is there somewhere).
After installing, I could open version 25.1 from Terminal, simply typing `emacs`. After rebooting, the installations seems to be completely gone. Performing `tree / | grep emacs-25` (and various alternatives) showed me that the only version 25 files are found in my `~/Downloads/` folder, containing the downloaded source code, i.e. there is nothing in '/usr/bin/` and the like. It seems no executable file was created.

But, not to worry... that tutorial provided me with the `.deb` package. I had a look for [ways to use this local package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt), and plumped for the `gdebi` variant. Trying to execute this, I see this:

[image: Error using package installer - gdebi]

Or on the command-line:

```
user@user:~/Downloads/emacs-25.1$ sudo gdebi emacs_25.1-1_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
A later version is already installed
```

So I looked at the meta-information of this package:

```
user@user:~/Downloads/emacs-25.1$ dpkg --info emacs_25.1-1_amd64.deb 

 new debian package, version 2.0.          <-- is this the problem?? -------
 size 41650584 bytes: control archive=355 bytes.
       0 bytes,     0 lines      conffiles            
     295 bytes,    10 lines      control              
 Package: emacs
 Priority: extra
 Section: checkinstall
 Installed-Size: 129208
 Maintainer: root@user
 Architecture: amd64
 Version: 25.1-1
 Provides: emacs
 Description: emacs25.1
```

Is the marked line really what is being taken into account, when comparing to the system's installed version 24?

#### Update: output of `apt-cache policy emacs`

```
test@test:~$ apt-cache policy emacs
emacs:
  Installed: 46.1
  Candidate: 46.1
  Version table:
 *** 46.1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

A quick search shows me that this might be a known occurrence. Any up-to-date fixes or methods to resolve this are welcome!

Comment: Please show us the output of `apt-cache policy emacs`

Comment: [This helpful post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/881930/why-is-this-emacs-package-versioned-at-46-1-26-is-the-highest-possible-major-ve) will help people understand this problem - and perhaps resolve it.