# Remove package installed with checkinstall from software updater

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, checkinstall

How can I stop software installed using `checkinstall` from being updated in the software updater?

In my case, I install emacs from source via `checkinstall` and set the version to 26. I have removed all system versions of emacs using `apt`.  Every time software updater pops up it wants to update emacs.  How can I stop this behaviour?

Edit:

TLDR: Ubuntu uses higher numbers than current emacs version for emacs package -- see
See [Why is this Emacs package versioned at 46.1? 26 is the highest possible major version today](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881930/why-is-this-emacs-package-versioned-at-46-1-26-is-the-highest-possible-major-ve)

Comment: ^Either that, or when installing using `checkinstall`, specify a higher version than anything likely to be in Ubuntu's repos.

Comment: try `apt-get purge emacs`  @muru -- he removed it

Comment: @muru thanks, I did look at that answer as well.  But I wasn't sure that was the proper thing to do for my case.  version 26 shouldn't be in the repos as it is still in development, I think they are on 24 in the repos

Comment: @ravery He removed the emacs installed via apt, but emacs installed via checkinstall is also registered as in apt/dpkg's databases (that's the whole point of using checkinstall).

Comment: @ravery yes, I did remove the system emacs using that method

Comment: @muru -- yes you use checkinstall so you can uninstall via apt which he did

Comment: @jenesaisquoi yes, but Ubuntu actually uses 40+ as the version numbers (I don't recall the reasons), so it will always be an upgrade over an actual 20-something version. See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=emacs

Comment: @muru oh... huh?  That sounds like the problem then, I will look into that

Comment: Related: [Why is this Emacs package versioned at 46.1? 26 is the highest possible major version today](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881930/why-is-this-emacs-package-versioned-at-46-1-26-is-the-highest-possible-major-ve)

Comment: @steeldriver that looks like an exact dupe if you want to dupe it, otherwise I will delete it. Thanks!